# How to draw the ellipse shape in graph using XCalc.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);

body {
  background-color:#34495e;
  color:#FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#top {
 
  position:absolute;
  left:350px;
  top:70px;
  
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size:30px;
  margin:0 0 10px 0;
}
input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], a.button {
 background-color:#FFF;
 color:#000;
 padding:5px;
 border: 5px solid #FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  margin:0 0 0 10px;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="button"]:hover, a.button:hover {
 border: 5px solid #DDD;
}
input[type="text"] {
  display:inline-block;
  height:20px;
  width: 290px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: 0;
}
#result {
  top:155px;
  position:absolute;
  left:350px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
 
  max-height:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.solved #result {
  max-height:2000px;
  padding:20px;
  color:#FFF;
}
.answer {
  clear:both;
  text-align:center;
}
.group {
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid #FFF;
  display:inline-block;
}
.group.operator {
  border:0;
}
.final {
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:60px;
  text-align:left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.error {
  background-color:#6B1010;
  padding:10px;
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="exmath.js"></script>
  
 //refer the link in exmath.js are using. https://github.com/davepagurek/XCalc/blob/master/js/XCalc.js

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exmath.css">//css file name.
  
</head>
<body>

<div id="top"><h1>Maths equation plotter</h1>
   f(x) = <input type="text" value="(x+4)^2*(x-6)+60sinx" id="input" /><input type="button" value="Graph" id="simplify" />
  </div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="result"></div>
  
  
  
  
  

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some code in  XCalc.js in that code running any equation type based on equation plot the graph but how to draw the ellipse shape in XCalc.js how to programming the code.For example (x^2/4^2)+(y^2/2^2)=0 in based on equation how to draw the ellipse shape please help me...

Comment: Never used the library or anything alike, but what do you expect the math parser to read from `(x+4)^2*(x-6)+60sinx`? Should be `(x+4)^2*(x-6)+60*sin(x)` imho.

Comment: @efkah its possible are not in my code to draw the ellipse shape.

Comment: Looks like your plotter only plots the first solution it finds, i.e. misses the negative solutions of your roots. Try plotting `y=sqrt(2)`. You will need to superposition the graphs of `y=+sqrt(2)`and `y=-sqrt(2)` to get a solution. Or do some (much) coding in the library... Same applies to your ellipse.

Comment: your function in graph form `y=+-sqrt(-x^2/4)` gets even unreal, check wolfram alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x^2%2F4^2%29%2B%28y^2%2F2^2%29%3D0

Comment: @efkah Its not support the y=sqrt(2) please any other suggestion to plot the ellipse shape.